# Microsoft Edge clean session

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge driver does not ensure clean session whenever it runs selenium tests. Is there an option I can specify to desired capabilities to fix this?

Comment: what do you mean by saying 'clean session'? If you're talking about cookies stored in edge, then you're able to clean them using `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();`

Comment: i want to clear cache, cookies, and history. In IE, you can just specify the property ie.ensureCleanSession = true in desiredCapabilities to get that done

Comment: Note: driver.manage().deleteAllCookies() is not working on Release 14393 MS edge Win 10 Sel 3.1.0

Comment: @Kozi, It works, but first you need to have a page open. See: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/5751773/#comment-2

Comment: @André Is it work for localhost? after opening a page from localhost it doesn't delete cookies.

Answer (score 5):

Just encounter that issue myself today so the only way I got it to work was pretty simple in the end. You have to check "Always clear this when I close the browser" in Edge settings (and select the things that you want to clear).

With that setting you will have clean session on each new driver initialization :)
[image: selenium edge clean session]

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be to open Edge in Private Mode (at least solved my problems with session and clearing cookies):

```c#
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("InPrivate", true);
this.edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the only way to achieve a clean session in Edge is to build it as you go. What I mean is, you must clear cookies and reload screens where necessary.

An example would be a login screen which navigates to a landing page having a popup arrive ~1-3 seconds after load.

- Edge login pages typically don't logout the previous tests user so a Logout is often required at the beginning of these test steps if Browser=Edge.
- The first time this all happens locally, the driver sees the popup, it's dismissed, and a cookie gets created which prevents the popup from triggering for the next test.

I don't know about your test framework, but I use ConfirmOnThisPage() methods anytime I move from one page to another. So, once I know the page has loaded, I can easily handle cookies about to be tested here with a call to a DeleteCookie(Cookie cookie) function which contains a page refresh from within my page confirmation method. I use the following:

```
public IWebDriver DeleteCookie(Cookie cookie){
    driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteCookieNamed(cookie);
    driver.Navigate().Refresh(); 
    return driver;
}
```