# How to launch Microsoft Edge in InPrivate with Selenium WebDriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I need help with launching Edge in InPrivate mode with Selenium and Java. I am not using Robot framework so cannot use the below solution:
[Open Edge in InPrivate mode using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067862/open-edge-in-inprivate-mode-using-selenium/46069818#46069818)

Also I tried the other solutions suggested by this solution, it did not work:
[How to start Edge browser in Incognito mode using selenium remote webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547933/how-to-start-edge-browser-in-incognito-mode-using-selenium-remote-webdriver)

So, not sure if there are any other solutions to it.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53950665/8754516) answer helped me. Namely,

```
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("InPrivate", true);
this.edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

FYI, there's also a `EdgeOptions` property called `UseInPrivateBrowsing`(at least in C#). Setting this flag to `true` only works for Microsoft Edge browsers that support the "W3C WebDriver Specification", according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51123890/8754516) post.