# Unable to open Edge in InPrivate mode using selenium web driver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, ui-automation

From the C# object model, it looks like this should do the trick, but the UseInPrivateBrowsing property has no effect at my end. Just opens a regular browser session in the edge.

```
var options = new EdgeOptions();
options.UseInPrivateBrowsing = true;
var driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

I am using the latest Selenium.WebDriver.MicrosoftDriver.

These are the installed packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.10.1" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.10.0" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver" version="2.40" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Selenium.Support" version="3.13.0" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.13.0" targetFramework="net47" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver.MicrosoftDriver" version="17.17134.0" targetFramework="net47" />
</packages>
```

How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: Which language do you use? JavaScript?

Comment: Using C# for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UseInPrivateBrowsing` property will only work for versions of the driver for Microsoft Edge that support the [W3C WebDriver Specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/). Unfortunately, these versions of the driver are only available in Windows Insider builds at the moment. Once a version of the driver is released to widely available versions of Windows 10, this property will work everywhere for Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Until `UseInPrivateBrowsing` works, you could try replacing just that line with:

```
options.AddArgument("inprivate");
```

that allowed me to open up an "InPrivate" window using Selenium.WebDriver 4.0.0-beta4.